# Get full name of Complex Type from ModelClientValidationRequiredIfRule method in custom ValidationAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, complextype, validationattribute

I am using the example at **[The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)** to create a **RequiredIf** validation attribute (it's about 1/3 down the page under the heading of "**A more complex custom validator**").  It all works fine with the exception of one scenario, and that is if I have the need to validate against a complex type.  For example, I have the following model:

```
public class MemberDetailModel
{
  public int MemberId { get; set; }
  // Other model properties here
  public MemberAddressModel HomeAddress { get; set; }
  public MemberAddressModel WorkAddress { get; set; }
}

public class MemberAddressModel
{
  public bool DontUse { get; set; }
  // Other model properties here

  [RequiredIf("DontUse", Comparison.IsEqualTo, false)]
  public string StreetAddress1 { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that when the attribute validation for the StreetAddress property is rendered, it get's decorated with the attribute of `data-val-requiredif-other="DontUse"`.  Unfortunately, since the address is a sub-type of the main model, it needs to be decorated with a name of **HomeAddress_DontUse** and not just **DontUse**.

Strangely enough, the validation works fine for server-side validation, but client-side unobtrusive validation fails with an JS error because JS can't find the object with a name of just "DontUse".

Therefore, I need to find a way to change the ModelClientValidationRequiredIfRule method to know that the property it is validating is a sub-type of a parent type, and if so, prepend the `ParentType_` to the "otherProperty" field (e.g. otherProperty becomes `HomeAddress_DontUse`.

I have tried passing in `typeof(MemberAddressModel)` as a parameter of the attribute, but even when debugging the attribute creation, I can't seem to find any reference to the parent type of HomeAddress or WorkAddress from that type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the suggestion from The Flower Guy, I was able to come up with the following which seems to work.  I simply modified the following in the customValidation.js file:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("requiredif", function (value, element, params) {
  if ($(element).val() != '') return true;
  var prefix = getModelPrefix(element.name); // NEW LINE
  var $other = $('#' + prefix + params.other);  // MODIFIED LINE
  var otherVal = ($other.attr('type').toUpperCase() == "CHECKBOX") ? ($other.attr("checked") ? "true" : "false") : $other.val();
  return params.comp == 'isequalto' ? (otherVal != params.value) : (otherVal == params.value);
});
```

I also added the following method to that file (within the JQuery block so as to be only privately accessible):

```
function getModelPrefix(fieldName) {
  return fieldName.substr(0, fieldName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1).replace(".","_");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Cannot do it exactly right now, but the problem is in the client javascript function:

jQuery.validator.addMethod("requiredif" ...

The js is not sophisticated enough to cope with complex view models where there may be a model prefix. If you take a look at Microsoft's jquery.validate.unobstrusive.js (in the Scripts folder over every MVC3 application), you will find some useful methods including getModelPrefix and appendModelPrefix. You can take a similar approach and change the requiredIf validation method - take a look at the equalto method in jquery.validate.unobstrusive.js for a helping hand.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I see the functions that MS uses in jquery.validate.unobstrusive.js, but I'm not quite sure how to implement them in my JS file.  If you get a chance, any help would be appreciated, otherwise, I'll keep playing around to figure it out.